# Starling 3D rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, rotation, starling-framework

Is there a way to rotate an object (plain graphic) around it's X axis using Starling (stage3D)?
There was rotationXYZ in "standard" Flash (stage) to do this and I am looking for similar solution.

Comment: well.. if you're using stage3D, have you actually looked into the api reference on rotations? an example of a google search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238061/how-do-you-combine-x-y-and-z-rotations-in-a-models-local-space-not-global

Comment: @user1916182  - this is not it , because of Starling is a 2d framework

Comment: wait, then why do you mention stage3D in the post? :S by the way, look at the link that i've posted, you could still make use of the matrix provided in the answers

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, these features are not implemented (see [forum page](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/25d-rotationx-rotationy-rotationz-and-z-property)) .But,  you can play with `transformationMatrix` of Starling's `DisplayObject`. Or if you are rendering your texture on runtime from ordinary Flash `DisplayObject` you can first give rotation to `DisplayObject` instance and then turn it into texture , very elegant..